# C++ My functions work within my Image class but not in the main routine

Tags: c++, function, oop, program-entry-point

The methods work in my other Image functions, but not in my main routine. 
Im sure its a simple issue, but I just can't figure it out...

I get a compile time error

```
    make
g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:21:35: error: ‘create2dArray’ was not declared in this scope
     testData = create2dArray(10, 8);
                                   ^
main.cpp:35:35: error: ‘fillArray’ was not declared in this scope
     fillArray(moreData, 8, 15, 255);
                                   ^
makefile:4: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I have properly included the image.h file in main, and all the other image functions work correctly, its just the array functions that appear to be out of scope somehow.

My question is how do I fix this error, and did I declair the methods themselves in the right location in my program? (they are in the image.cpp)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Here is my Image.h file:

```
#ifndef IMAGE_H
#define IMAGE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Image {
    public:
        Image();    // Default constructor
        ~Image();   // Default destructor
        Image(std::string title, int rows, int cols, int **I);  // Creates a Image object
        Image &operator=(const Image &I);   // Overloads the = operator for image objects
        bool operator==(const Image &I);    // Checks if two images are equal returning bool
        Image operator+(const Image &I);    // Adds the two images returning the resulting image
        int getCols();  // Returns the col of the object
        int getRows();  // Returns the rows of the object
        string getTitle(); // Returns the title of the image
        void histogram(int n); // Displays a histogram of the image to the user

        // Overloads the cout<< operator to print Image objects
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, const Image &I);

        // Overloads the cin>> operator to input Image objects
        friend istream& operator>>(istream &input, Image &I);

        // Creates a 2d array of size rows, containing arrays of size cols, 
        //  returns the resulting 2d array  
        friend int** create2dArray(int rows, int cols); 
        // Deletes a 2d array of int** taking in the array and size of the array as parameters
        friend void delete2dArray(int** array, int size);
        // Fills a 2d array with test data within the range of 1 and rangeHigh, 
        //  returns a 2d array. Takes the array, the size of the array, 
        //  and the highest number you want to generate as prams.
        friend void fillArray(int** array, int size, int rangeLow, int rangeHigh);
    private:
        string title;
        int cols; 
        int rows;
        int **data; 
};

#endif
```

And here are the functions themselves:

```
// Creates a 2d array of size rows, containing arrays of size cols, 
//  returns the resulting 2d array  
int** create2dArray(int rows, int cols)
{
    int **data;
    data = new int*[rows];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        data[i] = new int[cols];
    }

    return data;
}

// Deletes a 2d array of type int** taking in the array and the size of the array as parameters
void deleteArray(int** array, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        delete[] array[i];
    }

    delete[] array;
}

// Fills a 2d array with test data within the range of 1 and rangeHigh, returns a 2d array
// Takes the array, the size of the array, and the highest number you want to generate as prams.
void fillArray(int** array, int rows, int cols, int rangeHigh)
{
    int randomInt;

    // Fills each element of the array with a value between 1 and rangeHigh
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            randomInt = (rand()%rangeHigh) + 1;
            array[i][j] = randomInt;
        }
    }
}
```

The functions work in other functions like this one:

```
// Adds the two images returning the resulting image
Image Image::operator+(const Image &I)
{   
    // Checks to see if the images are the same size
    if(this->rows == I.rows && this->cols == I.cols) {
        int **newData = create2dArray(this->rows, this->cols);

        // Loops through each element of both arrays and creates a new array of the same
        //  size containing the average of the two arrays at that position
        for(int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this->cols; j++) {
                newData[i][j] = (this->data[i][j] + I.data[i][j]) / 2;
            }
        }

        cout << "working" << endl;

        Image img(this->title + " " + I.title, this->rows, this->cols, newData);

        cout << img;
        return img;

    } else {
        throw string("Incompatible size.");
    }
}
```

Here is the main.cpp:

```
#include "image.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int **testData;

    // Creates a 2d array of size 10 rows * 8 cols
    testData = create2dArray(10, 8);

    // Adds data to the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            testData[i][j] = i*j;
        }
    }

    // Creates another array of size 8 rows * 15 cols
    int **moreData;
    moreData = create2dArray(8, 15);

    // Adds data to the array
    fillArray(moreData, 8, 15, 255);

    Image testImage("Test", 10, 8, testData);
    Image additionalImage("Additional Image", 15, 10, moreData);

    cout << testImage;
    cout << additionalImage;

    Image testImage2;
    testImage2 = testImage;

    cout << testImage2;

    Image newImage;
    cin >> newImage;

    try {
        cout << "testImage + testImage2 = \n" << testImage + testImage2 << endl;
    } catch (string & e) {
        cout << "testImage + testImage2: " << e << endl;
    }

    try {
        cout << "testImage + newImage = \n" << testImage + newImage << endl;
    } catch (string & e) {
        cout << "testImage + newImage: " << e  << endl;
    }


    cout << "good" << endl;
    if(testImage == newImage) {
        cout << endl << testImage.getTitle() << " is equal to " << newImage.getTitle() << endl;
    }

    if(!(testImage == additionalImage)) {
        cout << endl << testImage.getTitle() << " is not equal to " << additionalImage.getTitle() << endl;
    }

    delete testData;
}
```

Comment: Where is your main.cpp?

Comment: Oh my bad.. Give me a second

Comment: I added the main.cpp

Comment: As the error messages tell you, when compiling `main()`, the  compiler needs to have visibility of the function `main()` calls.   It doesn't.   The `friend` declarations are in the scope of your class, not global.    The fix is to have separate declarations of the functions (outside class `Image`).   Also, get out of the habit of placing `using namespace std` in header files - if you search here, or even more generally with google, you'll find explanations of why that is VERY bad practice.

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the missing function prototypes for `create2dArray()` and `fillArray()` in the header file, so that they are declared within `main.cpp`, and be sure to compile and link the source file that implements them along with `main.cpp`.